# How do I get Eclipse to switch to SVN view on synchronize with repository?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using Eclipse (Indigo) with an SVN plug in.

I right-clicked in the project view, selected `Team > Synchronize With Repository`, then it prompted with something like 'we want to switch to the synchronize perspective?  Ok?' -- I made the mistake of checking the `remember my decision' checkbox, and then I clicked 'No'.

So now when I do a 'synchronize' it doesn't take me to the Sync perspective.  How do I tell Eclipse I changed my mind, and get it to show me the Sync perspective on sync?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Window->Preferences->Team

"Open the associated perspective when a synchronize operation completes"
select Always or Prompt